# Problems with listView.setOnItemClickListener

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a problem in this code. I need to execute the code in the `listView.setOnItemClickListener()` but the program not enter in this function.
Any ideas?

```
adapter = new CustomerListAdapter(Activity.this);

ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);

listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Activity.this, DetailActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("sk", adapter.getSK(position));
        Activity.this.startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_DETAIL);
    }
});
```

Comment: what happens when you click on a list item?

Comment: What do yo have inside an list view item?

Comment: Do you have button or ImageButton inside the convertView?

Comment: Maybe problem id of ListView. Do you have same id "listView1" in project?

Comment: Do you get errors? Try debugging this code and see what happens if you put a breakpoint within the listener. This code looks fine to me (if Activity and DetailActivity are correct). Also more code could help.

Comment: What do u have inside your listview? It can be your layout xml which could cause the click issue.

Comment: In the layout xml i have:

<ListView android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/listView1" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ListView>
<Button android:text="Button" android:id="@+id/button1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
</LinearLayout>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
listView.setItemsCanFocus(false);
```

Also make sure you add the following code for every clickable object inside your list view items.

```
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

Comment: I've some testViews. I must also add the code in these things?

Comment: Yes, add this code to those testViews and let me know about the result.

Comment: Unfortunately, the result doesn't change

Comment: In the layout xml i have: <ListView android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/listView1" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ListView> <Button android:text="Button" android:id="@+id/button1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>